# UTP 6A cable with FTP 6A connector

Tags: cabling, utp

Can I use cat. 6A FTP connector with cat. 6A UTP cable? I've already bought UTP cable but i cannot find 6A UTP connectors, only FTP. Will it work or will it generate some interferences?

Comment: What type of cable (stranded or solid-core) and the cable use case? You cannot meet the standard and pass the category test suite building your own stranded patch cords, and solid-core for horizontal cable punches down on wall plates and patch panels, not plug connectors.

Answer (score 1):

Shielded connectors with an unshielded cable shouldn't really be a problem. Not  properly grounded or interrupted shielding works as an antenna, but for those very short lengths that shouldn't be noticeable.

However, you should only ever terminate horizontal cabling - which is solid-core - with a wall jack or a patch panel, never with a connector. Horizontal cabling requires to be certified after deployment. Proper cable testers for certification are expensive but can also be rented.

Flexible, stranded patch cables should never by DIY terminated but bought ready to use - mostly because the required certification doesn't pay off.